# selenium css selector cannot get target while target is visiable and selectable in inspection mode

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors

I am looking at [this page](https://www.datagrapple.com/Home/Grapple#/10082/HISTOGRAPH/1M/5/1432/N/3), free registration is required to log in.

In this page, I am trying to select "#histo-line-chart > g > g.hist-container > g.hist-top-graph > g.hist-spreadlines > g".

```
def login():
    url = "https://www.datagrapple.com/Account/Login"
    browser = create_browser(
        r'C:/Users/YOURADDRESS/webdrivers/chromedriver.exe')  # change addr when necessary
    browser.get(url)
    browser.find_element_by_id('UserName').send_keys('EXIA2018') # valid demo
    browser.find_element_by_id('Password').send_keys('102938')
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/form/fieldset/div[3]/div/button').click()
    return browser

obj_path = '#histo-line-chart > g > g.hist-container > g.hist-top-graph > g.hist-spreadlines > g'
WebDriverWait(browser, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, obj_path)))  # added according to NatalSnowyFox's suggestion. 
browser.find_element_by_css_selector(obj_path)
```

Then I got this error.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"histo-line-chart > g > g.hist-container > g.hist-top-graph > g.hist-spreadlines > g"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=79.0.3945.130)
```

When I paste this css selector to the browser in inspect mode, it can successfully find the target.

I am using Python 3.7.6 and selenium 3.141.0. I've reinstalled selenium in case.

please guide me through, thank you ahead.

### update 1

added explict wait codes according to NatalSnowyFox's suggestion, but get timesout error even I extended timeout to 60 seconds

Comment: The page is probably being loaded dynamically by javascript and is not actually present in the page source.

Comment: @ERIC can you share the demo set of credentials?

Comment: @DebanjanB, I added in the questions.

Comment: @isopach I can see the elements in chrome browser, so I guess selenium can do the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to use WebDriverWait(driver, time).until(your condition)? Maybe browser just need time to locate it, try to use explicit wait.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"your selector"))
```

Instead "visibilityOfElementLocated" you can use any other conditions (presence of element located, visibility of, clickable element..etc, depends what you need)

https://selenium.dev/docs/site/en/webdriver/waits/

Comment: Thanks, I added to the code, but still cannot get the element.

Comment: Hi, Eric, pls, try to use Xpath instead css selector, maybe it will work..."//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='g' and @class='hist-spread-line-splited']"